# Multiple Colliders in foreach loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this line of codes right here

```cs
void BasicMeleeAttack()
{ 
    _playerAnim.SetTrigger("meleeAttack");
    Collider[] hitTarget = 
        Physics.OverlapSphere(MeleeAttackPosition.position, attackRange, enemyLayer);

    foreach (Collider enemy in hitTarget)
    {
        if (enemy.transform.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().EnemyDamaged(_playerAttackDamage);
        }   
    }
}
```

And lets say I only hit one enemy but that enemy has 2 box colliders (one is triggered and one is coliding), a character controller and also a child object that has also a box collider. Does that mean the line in this `foreach` loop would execute 3 times? because there are a total of 3 colliding components excluding the children object one?

I test this with Debug.log(), it executes 3 times but when i restart the engine , it only executes once(could be a bug) and when i remove the line
`if(enemy.transform.tag == "Enemy")`
it only executes twice so this really bugging my mind and i have no idea how this works or whether my laptop just has bugs, also I'm using the newest unity version as well as the Visual studio one.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be one for every collider that the sphere overlaps.

Now, if this were me, I'd pass a unique melee attack id, or some other id so the same enemy wouldn't be "hit" more than once for each attack. A time (which is a float) could be used as a unique value. The Enemy.EnemyDamaged method could accept a float value and compare it to the last attack, and if they're the same, skip taking damage.

e.g.

```
private float _lastAttack = 0;
public void TakeDamage ( int damage, float id )
{
    if ( id == _lastAttack ) return;
    _lastAttack = id;
    // ...
}
```

You could also just get a random integer value on an attack, and pass that through instead. All valid options.

Colliders also have an attachedRigidbody that you could check against and make sure you only attack if the attachedRigidbody is unique. But you didn't mention if you had RigidBody's attached to your enemies.